# g++ from msys2 is generating .o file only

Tags: g++, msys2

`g++  -c -I"C:/Users\hp/Documents/Projects/arb"  test_arb.cpp`

it is generating `test_arb.o` file but no `.exe`

`./a.out` is not working either.

How do I run it then?

PS: I am on windows 10. I have msys2 installed followed by g++ installed via pacman on msys2.

Comment: `-c` means you want `.o` instead of `.exe`. Remove it if it's not the case.

Comment: how do I specify path to arb then ?

Comment: What's "arb"? You don't need to change anything else.

Comment: Since I am facing another issue with library path so was confused.